# CSS Mixins in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

what is CSS Mixins? i am seeing that as a tab in extjs documentation?

I am trying to understand http://oocss.org/spec/css-mixins.html
How to use CSS Mixins in extjs?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExtJS uses the Sass pre-compiler for its CSS themes.

A mixin lets you define and re-use a chunk of CSS.

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins

You can read more about ExtJS theming here:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/theming